# Why does my java program keep printing the exception in try catch loop?

Tags: java

I can't seem to find the problem. The output is correct, until the exception is caught. When I catch it, the program prints:

> Please Give An Integer: Not Valid Integer, Please Try Again Please
>   Give An Integer: Not Valid Integer, Please Try Again...

infinitely. I know it must be a stupid mistake.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4Exercise1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean caught;
        int number=-1;
        int counter = 0;
        int[] array = new int[5];

        do {
            caught = false;
            System.out.print("Please Give An Integer: ");

            try {
                number = sc.nextInt();
            }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Not Valid Integer, Please Try Again");
                caught = true;
            }

            if (caught == false) {
                counter += 1;
                array[counter] = number;
            }

        }while(counter < 5);

        System.out.println("Your input was:");
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: The call to `nextInt` doesn't consume the non-integer token - so if you put in something other than a non-integer, it will just try the same input repeatedly.

Comment: Don’t use boolean literals in expression. Replace `x == false` with `! x` etc.

Comment: The fix is to call `nextLine()` or `next()` in the exception handler, to throw away the bad input.

Comment: @JonSkeet so what am i supposed to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes! i just saw that on a similar question and it worked! Thanks and sorry for the already answered question!

Answer (score -2):

To fix this add this

```
try {
    number = sc.nextInt();
}catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Not Valid Integer, Please Try Again");
    caught = true;
}finally {
    sc.nextLine();
}
```

**Reason**: according to [Scanner Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a scanner throws an `InputMismatchException`, the scanner will
>   not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be
>   retrieved or skipped via some other method.

---

**Issue not mentioned in the question but may occurs future errors:**

also you have an other issue that you have to fix it, The problem is here

```
if (caught == false) {
      counter += 1;
      array[counter] = number;
}
```

Actually the exception occurs when you increment the  counter (which is initialized to 0) before assigning value to your array, so at the last value counter will be 5, and array[5] will occur `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (size 5, index 5)

To solve it, please replace it with this

```
if (!caught) {
       array[counter++] = number;
 }
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to fix this though.. I tried it and the same happens

Comment: @Bashir While you are correct that there is an issue that would cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and your code fixes this, this isn't really what the question was about and you are kind of solving a Problem the asker didn't even know he had. (The current question is about how to fix the endless loop that happens if you ever enter something that isn't an int)

Comment: @push_ebp: "instead only write to the second element in the array every time." <- What? That is not correct at all. The code from bashir works but as already mentioned isn#t really fixing the problem the asker wanted to fix

Comment: the program is supposed to ask for 5 integers and place them in an array to print them at the end. So my counter counts the valid integers

Comment: Note the voter, but this question has [quite a few duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=InputMismatchException++infinite) and gets asked multiple times a week. Please consider flagging as a duplicate (or voting once you have enough reputation) instead of answering.

Comment: @Savior regardless the duplicated question, he wasn't aware of an other issue related to his algorithm... whatever ..